# VBA - Custom Ribbon Tabs in MS Excel add-in

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

I develop, for our department, an MS Excel add-in that includes a custom ribbon tabs that shows up when user lunch the add-in and hide some MS Excel tabs that we do not needs.
This custom ribbon   includes a quit function to unload the add-in.
The problem is that the company does provide some add-in with custom tab.

I would like to know, how I can hide temporary their custom tab and show them when the user quit out add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply enable/disable the company's add-ins, using:

```
Application.AddIns("name of the add in here").Installed = False
```

Of course, considering you know the other add-in names.